# All applications of previous answers fail -#1062 - duplicate entry '1' for key 'primary'

Tags: mysql, indexing, import, export

This question has been asked many times but none of the help offered has solved my problem, possibly because as a newby I am not correctly applying the answers.

The code below was produced by accessing the on-line databases I am developing for the local church(where the various PHP pages call the data correctly and generally do what I expected) and using the phpMyAdmin Export command.

My original development area running on a localserver on my PC failed, so I created a new local server, using phpMyAdmin. I created the databases I needed - terrier and graveyard. No tables as yet. I then ran the file I had obtained on-line by the Export command.

I expected the file produced by Export would work when I run it on the local server using Import. But I get the #1062 - duplicate entry '1' for key 'primary' (or variation on that message) whatever I try

I have only included the graveyard file as far as the admin section. I never get as far as the next section! The terrier one is identical apart from tables and data and produces the same error.

Thanks.

Ian

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.2.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Mar 18, 2015 at 01:17 PM
-- Server version: 5.0.95-log
-- PHP Version: 5.5.14

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `graveyard`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `admin`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
  `adminId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `admin`
--

INSERT INTO `admin` (`adminId`, `userName`, `password`) VALUES
(1, 'wardens', 'Bega&1120');
```

Comment: I hope that password isn't a real user's password...

Answer (score 0):

Apperently you are importing the data into an already populated table.

Notice that there is no `USE` command.  What controls which database (`terrier` or `graveyard`) the INSERTs will go into?

If that does not ring a bell, walk through the dataflow in more detail.  Think about providing your grandmother a numbered list of instructions to follow.